# slug Django field; do we need this?

Tags: django, web

I am beginning to learn Django and get this data related "slug":

> A short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs. For example, in a typical blog entry URL:
>
> https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2008/apr/12/spring/
> the last bit (spring) is the slug.

Why do we need this and how to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slug it's a way of generating a valid URL. 
Its advise to generate the slug, rather than setting it manually.

Example:

```
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)
```